# If there is no value in the table, then query should return 0

Tags: php, mysql

this is my query

```
select (max(booking_id),0) as bookingID from booking;
```

If there is no value in the table, then query should return 0. How could i do this??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two alternatives:

1. Using `IFNULL`:

   ```
   select IFNULL(max(booking_id),0)) as bookingID from booking;
   ```
2. Using `COALESCE`:

   ```
   select COALESCE(max(booking_id),0)) as bookingID from booking;
   ```

**Explanation:**

`IFNULL` can be used only in mysql. But `COALESCE` can be used in almost all RDBMSs.
`COALESCE` returns the first parameter in the list which is not null.

Comment: @KedarB: IFNULL is for mysql only. But COALESCE will work will almost all RDBMSs.